# Help with chapter 1 exerice 6 from "Differential Forms" by Carmo

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-forms

I am currently reading Carmo's book about differential forms. I tried excercise 6 from chapter 1, but I am a bit confused. Here is the excercise:

> Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a diff. map. Assume that $m<n$ and let $\omega$ be a $k$-form in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $k>m$. Show that $f^*\omega=0$.

My idea was that we have more different $df_{i_k}$ (we should have $n$ many, right?) and then $k<n$ so there is some $i_k$ in the definition of $f^*\omega$ where $df_{i_k} \wedge df_{i_k}$ so this is $0$.

In the exercise, they said that $k>m$ not $k>n$ so my argument would be false. In the book he always uses the notation $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Is this a mistake in the exercise or is there a different way that I do not see?

I'm glad if someone helps me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If $k>m$, what are the possible $k$-forms on $\Bbb R^m$?

Comment: Well you can only have k-forms up to m right?

Comment: But the $\omega$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: More or less. The only $2$-form on $\Bbb R$ is identically zero.

Comment: And pullback preserves degree, i.e. the pullback along $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of a $k$-form 
on $Y$ is a $k$-form on $X$, so what happens when you pullback a form of degree $k>m$ to $\mathbb R^m$, when you can have at most forms of degree $m$?

Comment: Think about $f^*\omega$, not $\omega$.

Comment: $f^*\omega$ is a k-form in $\mathbb{R}^m$ right?

Comment: Ohhh I think I got it. Since this is a k-form in $\mathrm{R}^m$ and k>m this implies that the only k-form has to be 0

Comment: Exactly, $f^*\omega$ is of degree $k>m$, and so it can only be $0$

Comment: Thank you so much you two!!! That really helped me understand the math more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this post officially closed here the summary.

## In general

for every k-form in $\mathbb{R}^m$ there are $\binom{m}{k}$ different basis vectors. This implies there are no non-trivial k-forms in $\mathbb{R}^m$ if $k > m$.

## For this exercise

Since $f^*\omega$ is a k-form in $\mathbb{R}^m$, but $k>m$ we can only have the k-form $f^*\omega = 0$